# Cannot install or try live elementary OS

Tags: system-installation

Booted up nicely, I first choose install.
The e logo appeared and then this error message came.
The same error message happens when I choose boot without installing.
What could be wrong ?
System:
-GA-H270M-DS3H
-Intel i7 6700K
-16GB Crucial RAM
-spare 250 GB Samsung SSD with macOS-HS installed.
Windows 10 and macOS are successfully running on separate SSD's that are not connected during my elementary OS install attempt.

[image: Error during setup]

Comment: I would start looking at your BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I had to use the older 2.0 USB port on the back.
But still I wonder what people with only USB 3.0 ports have to do then (besides burning a DVD) ?
I'm typing this on the "try without installing" option of Elemenary :) .

My own best guess is that the Elementary.ISO doesn't have a compatible driver for my mainboard.

Comment: Just to follow-up...you were able to install by moving your USB drive to a 2.0 port?

Comment: Yes, that is the only thing I did to try Elementary OS.

Comment: Once elementary was installed did the 3.0 port(s) function correctly?